# Cant multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python, python-2.7, typeerror

I'm trying to make a Inch to centimetre (And vice versa) converter with Python.

```
print "CM TO INCH (VV) CONVERSION. ENTER SPECIFIED NUMBER:"
inches = 2.54 #centimetres
cms = 0.393701 #inches
number = raw_input()
answercms = number * inches
answerinches = number * cms
print "%d centimetres are %d inches. %d inches are %d centimetres." % (number, answerCms, number, answerinches)
```

After running the script in Powershell it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "inchcm.py", line 5, in <module>
     answercms = number * inches
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

I know this question has come up once or twice but I dont understand the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string. You can't multiply a string with a number, so you need to convert the number string to an actual number format first, for instance with the [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) function:

```
number = raw_input()
answercms = float(number) * inches
```

You can use [`type()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#type) for checking the actual type of a variable:

```
>>> type(number)
<type 'str'>
>>> type(float(number))
<type 'float'>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's the first time I've got a thorough answer.